# Accessing color value of a conditionally formatted cell (or identifying a conditionally formatted cell)

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Can I somehow find out if a cell is conditionally formatted? I don't mean if there is a CF rule in a particular cell, but if it is true.

My idea was to do something like this (in the immediate window) `?ActiveSheet.Range("D58").Interior.ColorIndex`, but this returns `-4142` even though the cell is filled with blue.

---

For context: My CF is checking if a cell value matches the value of a calculation, like this: `"=A1+A50<>A24"` and applies the CF if this is true. It's good to know if the two values don't match, it means somewhere there is a mistake. However, it'd be even better if I could, for example, insert a comment in cell `A24` to show the user what result the calculation yields. Otherwise they have to check it for themselves.

Comment: `.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`.

Comment: In order to check if a range (`rng`) is conditionally formatted you can use: `rng.FormatConditions.count`. If it returns `0`, it is not conditionally formatted. If you need the real interior color (with or without conditional formatting) you can use `rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` as @BigBen already stated.

Comment: You can also just run the rules the conditional format uses to determine if it's true independent of whether the cell is formatted or not.